# Setting the src attribute of an already-existing script tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I try to set the src attribute of a script tag that had another value for the src attribute, the attribute is modified but the script doesn't execute.

I know there are other alternatives like creating a new script tag and setting its src attribute, but why is setting the src attribute of an already-existing script tag completely useless?

Comment: Because it's not a dynamic link to the resource when the browser loads it parses the script tag and includes the src attribute or the body of the tag. Updating it later doesn't cause the browser to reload the include.

Comment: @AdamH perhaps but I think it's a worthwhile question. Updating an `<iframe>` "src" attribute does reload the frame, for example.

Comment: @Pointy iFrame is an entirely different type of object. If you update the attributes on any element except style and script they have an immediate effect.

Comment: @AdamH Oh I understand; my point was that it's not intrinsically clear if you don't spend a lot of time curled up with the spec.

Comment: @Pointy sorry if it's coming across as something everyone should know, I didn't intend on it coming across like that. For the record I have never read the spec, I've just worked with it for a long time.

Comment: Sure and it had never crossed my mind to try updating a script "src" attribute either :)  I just meant that there are "why does it work this way" questions that are trivial or pointless, but this one is less like that (to me).

Comment: updating the href attribute of an already existing link tag whether it be for style or whatever works

Comment: @YousefEssam I did say that if you update the attributes on any element _except script and style_ that it has an immediate effect, I never said anything about a link tag not reacting to changes to it's attributes.

Comment: @Pointy I never implied that this question was trivial or pointless, i provided a direct and consise answer to the question that was asked. I'm not sure the problem is here.

Comment: @AdamH don't worry, I'm not upset or annoyed or anything at all bad, and I sincerely appreciate your concern and your solid answer.

Answer (score 4):

Because the [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) says so.

> Changing the src, type, nomodule, async, defer, crossorigin,
>   integrity, and referrerpolicy attributes dynamically has no direct
>   effect; these attributes are only used at specific times described
>   below.

I won't copy the [whole process paragraph](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model) here as it is rather long, but long story short: each script element is a small state machine, and the `src` attribute is only used in one specific state, when the element first processed (prepare step in the linked paragraph).

Comment: Is that only for the script tag or for other tags like img and iframe?

Comment: There is no similar mention in the documentation of those elements, so it should work. It's easy to give it a quick test if you so need. (`img`'s `src` and `iframe`'s `src` work).