# Dynamic script tag not loading, can't see network traffic for it

Tags: javascript, dom, deferred-execution

This code doesn't seem to load dynamically.  Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="sovrn-ad" async defer crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var scriptElement = document.getElementById('sovrn-ad');

        if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
            scriptElement.src = "https://ap.lijit.com/www/delivery/fpi.js?z=1056094&width=320&height=50";
        } else {
            scriptElement.src = "https://ap.lijit.com/www/delivery/fpi.js?z=1056094&width=320&height=50";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you meaning to load the same script source regardless of window width? Also, I don't believe dynamically changing the script src like this will work. See the linked duplicate answer. Generally third party libraries that require an additional script such as _Google Analytics_ use the `document.createElement('script');` method to create a script and append it to the document head causing it to be executed immediately. You may want to look into that route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the src attribute of an already-existing script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408573/setting-the-src-attribute-of-an-already-existing-script-tag)

Comment: Maybe, doesnt really have an answer.  Is there a way way to do this? Will appending to the document put it in the same spot as it was read to do it?

Comment: Updated with an answer and example below. Tested in jsfiddle to confirm that it works as expected. Let me know if I misread any of the requirements but I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you're trying to dynamically load a script based off the window's conditional width. In addition, based on the comment, it sounds like you need the updated script to load right after it has been placed in the document. To do this, try the following solution:

```
<script id="init-script" type="text/javascript">
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = 'async';
    script.defer = 'defer';
    script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    if(window.width < 480) {
        script.src = "Script if less than 480px";
    } else {
        script.src = "Script if greater than 480px";
    }
    insertAfter(document.getElementById('init-script'), script);
</script>
```

**What this does:**

The above script is doing a few things.

1. First, it defines a function called `insertAfter()` that will effectively insert your new element after this script tag but before any additional siblings.
2. Second, it then defines the script tag using the attributes you defined above and also provides the conditional logic based on the `window.width < 480` to load the appropriate script source value.
3. Finally, it passes the current script `id` element found using `document.getElementById` and the newly created script element to your original function which will append it directly below the script tag. Depending on where you place the `init-script` it will either append directly below in the `head` or `body` element.

***Credit:***

`insertAfter()` function derived from this answer: [How to insert an element after another element in JavaScript without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-insert-an-element-after-another-element-in-javascript-without-using-a-lib)

Comment: referenceNode.nextSibling is NULL, is that ok?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem right. Did you make sure to apply the `id` to the script tag itself? It may not be finding that element in the DOM otherwise.

Comment: There is a comment that NULL will still work on your reference link so it should be ok.

Comment: That should work then. It will probably put it at the bottom of the wrapping tag. Right before the `</body>` tag in your case if no sibling is available.